# Show large information in a map (millions of points)

Tags: cartography, leaflet, heat-map

I have millions of points (census data) about 1.5Gb in a text file. But I only want to show an area based on this points like a heat map, so maybe I have to build polygons based on these points. What is the correct way for do this? How can I start with this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As it stands I think your question is too broad for our focussed Q&A format.  Consequently, I recommend that you look through our most [frequent questions tagged `heatmap`](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heatmap?sort=frequent&pageSize=15) to review similar previous questions here with a view to editing yours to make it more focussed on where you are stuck.